# Change of measure for measures on different spaces

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, conditional-probability, radon-nikodym

For two measures $\nu, \mu$ that are defined on the same measure space with $\nu = \int f d\mu$, it is a well known result, mostly used in the context of the radon nikodym theorem, that for an integrable $g$:
$$\int g d\nu = \int g d(\int f d\mu) = \int g f d\mu.$$

My question is if there is some equivalent or related statement if two measures are not defined on the same space. In particular, I am interested in the following setting:
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $X:(\Omega, \mathcal{A})\rightarrow (\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{F})$ and $Y:(\Omega, \mathcal{A})\rightarrow (\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{G})$ be two random variables that map into different spaces.
Now assume that a regular conditional distribution exists (let $F\in \mathcal{F})$:
$$\mathbb{P}_Y(F) = \int_{\mathcal{X}} \mathbb{P}_{Y|X=x}(F) d\mathbb{P}_X(x).$$

Now my question is, given I have an integral like this:
$$\int_{\mathcal{Y}}h(y) d\mathbb{P}_Y(y)= \int_{\mathcal{Y}}h(y)d(\int\mathbb{P}_{Y|X=x} d\mathbb{P}_X)= \int ... d\mathbb{P}_X,$$

can I somehow write it as an integral where I integrate against the measure $d\mathbb{P}_X$? How would that look like if it was possible? Do I need the Radon Nikodym theorem somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{\mathcal{Y}}h(y) d\mathbb{P}_Y=\int_{\mathcal{X}}d\mathbb{P}_X\cdot\int_{\mathcal{Y}}h(y)d\mathbb{P}_{Y/X}$$
In general:
$$\int_{\mathcal{X\times Y}}f(x,y) d\mathbb{P}_{Y\circ X}=\int_{\mathcal{X}}d\mathbb{P}_X\cdot\int_{\mathcal{Y}}f(x,y)d\mathbb{P}_{Y/X}$$

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I dont understand in your "in general" statement the left hand side: you seem to integrate over a joint measure, i.e., Y and X but you only have an integral over the space $\mathcal{Y}$

Comment: I correct the error.